# how to use babel legacy decorators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I am getting this error message

"src\screens\LoginScreen.js: Cannot use the decorators and decorators-legacy plugin together
ERROR
Building JavaScript bundle: error"

here is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
  };
};
```

I add babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy to devDepencies in package.json file

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.23",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.5"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types --save
```

And then you have to change **babel.config.js** like below;

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true}]
    ]
};
```